# Tools/Script to check Vulnerabilities

Tags: php, security, xss

There is a tool or maybe better, a server side script to check if your site is secure against SQL Injection / XSS ?

I'm Using PHP.

I looked a bit on google, but i'm asking you for a precise answer, and also because i don't trust so much things found on google, since i am not really expecienced.

Comment: No, there is no one-step way to prove that your site is not vulnerable to XSS. Security is a process, not a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are [scanners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_security_scanner) that can check your application for common vulnerabilities. These will not prove that your application is secure, but still may be useful to find any security holes.

Edit: I had some success with [IronWasp](http://ironwasp.org/) and [Zap](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project).

Comment: IronWasp works fine. exactly what I was looking for.